# Better request.GET for multiple form fields?

Tags: python, django

Right now I have this where I have 3 fields:

```
<form action="/calc/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="pv">
    <input type="text" name="n">
    <input type="text" name="r">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

And I'm defining it like so:

```
def calc(request):
    if 'pv' in request.GET and 'n' in request.GET and 'r' in request.GET:
        pv = request.GET['pv']
        n = request.GET['n']
        r = request.GET['r']
        return render(request, 'main/index.html',
            {
                'pv': pv,
                'n': n,
                'r': r,
            })
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Is there a better/shorter way to write the if condition statement? Instead of writing if 'pv' and 'n' and 'r', etc...?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `all`

```
if all(x in request.GET for x in ['pv', 'n', 'r']):
```

But then is it really likely that someone will call this url without all 3? it may be worth just checking one.

You could just use the `.get` dictionary lookup and provide a default where it doesn't exist, `.get` will return None by default

```
request.GET.get('pv')
request.GET.get('pv', 'default')
```

Also, instead of referencing them directly, you should just make a form and let django handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a Django Form class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/

```
from django import forms

class CalcForm(forms.Form):
    pv = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    n = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    r = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and the create an instance of this CalcForm in your view to render in template.

```
def calc(request):
    form = CalcForm(request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
       # all fields are valid
       data = form.cleaned_data
```

The advantage here is that Django does a validation for you. If your function hits the database, Django also prevents SQL injections.